# Character encoding issue after migration to elastic search 6.8

Tags: elasticsearch, character-encoding, special-characters, upgrade, elasticsearch-6.8

Recently we have migrated from elastic search 5.6 to 6.8

The issue is when sample query containing special character is run it's not functioning properly

My query contains some thing like

```
{
 "query":{
 "Match_pharse":{
     "Article_title":"Á©"
 }
 }}
```

How to make this special character read

Comment: May I ask you what exactly goes wrong? Does ES throw an error, or it returns wrong/no results?

Comment: It returns no result....so when I remove this special character I can get results

Comment: Another thing, I just noticed that the name of the query is misspelled. It should be [`"match_phrase"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) instead of `"Match_pharse"`. May you please check that it is spelled correctly in your code?

Comment: Sorry that might be my typo..

Comment: Elasticsearch in principle supports Unicode, so the problem can be in how the query is serialized (prepared for sending), how the data is analyzed. Please show also your mapping and a couple of example documents that should match this query.